# Curl download error in Zypper

Tags: curl, suse, zypper

I'm trying to install a package via zypper:

```
sudo zypper install ambari-server

Download (curl) error for 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/AMBARI-1.x/repos/suse11/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: couldn't connect to host
```

Apparently zypper can't connect to the server. However I'm able to download the file via cUrl directly:

```
 curl  'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/AMBARI-1.x/repos/suse11/repodata/repomd.xml'

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <repomd xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/repo">
      [...]
 </repomd>
```

I'm behind a proxy that is set up in `/etc/sysconfig/proxy`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `sudo` didn't preserve my environment variables like `$http_proxy` and `$no_proxy`.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Call sudo with the parameter -E to preserve the current environment
2. Configure sudo to keep the proxy variables:
   Run visudo as root and add the following:

   `Defaults      env_keep+=http_proxy`

   `Defaults      env_keep+=https_proxy`

   `Defaults      env_keep+=no_proxy`